# Syntax issue on the source

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, migration

I'm migrating a SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2019, I have used Microsoft Data Migration Assistant, to look for search any breaking changes, issues or syntax errors.

I getting errors for some of my procedures:

> Object [dbo].[PROCEDURE1] has syntax errors. Must declare the variable or parameter "@SINI". Error number 70590. For more details, please see: Line 9, Column 16.

This is my procedure:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCEDURE1] 
    @Refer AS varchar, 
    @Ret Decimal OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @SIni AS Decimal

    SET @SIni= (SELECT Ini FROM Table1 WHERE Refer = @Refer)
    SET @Ret = @SINI
```

Comment: I guess you have a server with case sensitive collation. What does `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation');` return? In this situation, change this line `SET @Ret = @SINI` to `SET @Ret = @SIni`.

Comment: Also, fix your data types. *Never* declare your data types without the appropriate length, scale, and precision.

Comment: Why such overly wordy and complicated code? Just use `SET @Ret = (select Ini FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Refer = @Refer);` You don't need a local variable. You don't need TWO assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have a server with case sensitive collation. As is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), the *identifiers for variables, GOTO labels, temporary stored procedures, and temporary tables are in the default collation of the server instance.*. You may check this with the following simple statement:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation');
```

But, to fix the error, use the correct case-sensitive variable name:

```
...
SET @Ret = @SIni
...
```

As an additional note, declare your data types with the appropriate length (as @Larnu commented). The length attribute is optional, and in case of parameter declaration the SQL Server assigns `1` as length, so the `@Refer` parameter has data type `varchar(1)`.